# Is there any design pattern to execute same method differently based on context of execution

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

I am refactoring some code, and what I want is to let that method execute extra operations based on context in which it is executing.

For example: 
if current method is as follows

```
public void func1() {

 /// Operation Set 1

 /// Operation Set 2
 // Operation Set 3
 // Operation Set 4

}
```

I want it to be something like this:

```
// After refactoring
punlic void func1() {

/// Operation Set 1

if( context == FULL || context == EXEC_REQUIRED )
{
   /// Operation Set 2

    if( context === EXEC_REQUIRED )
    {
       // Operation Set 3
       // Operation Set 4
    }
}

}
```

So for this I am just wondering if there is any design pattern already?

Currently I can think about 2 solutions

1. Pass context as parameter to method from caller, but if I follow this then I will have to make changes to all the functions in call stack, but those function may not use this context.
2. Define something like ContextProvider as a static class. And whenever we need context info, ask ContextProvider about it. Problem here is, application is multi threaded , so static doesnt seem right idea.

If you have any solution, that will be helpful.

Comment: According to the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), what you describe may not be the best idea (from the clean-code point of view). I would try a polymorphic approach (for example, the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)).

Comment: I agree... But it is not possible in my case, as everything is actually happening in constructors ( base to base constructors to be more precise). Problem I mentioned is simpler version only. So the only option I have is to provide context somehow to this constructors and use ifelse logic.

Comment: The question makes me think of the [State pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot to **Subjectivity** which has been subject of research efforts (mainly) in the Smalltalk community since several years. The latest I am aware of is implemented in [Pharo](http://pharo.org/) package [Subjectopia](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/subjectopia) (Daniel Langone. [Subjectopia — Unifying Subjectivity](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/masters/Lang11b.pdf). Master's Thesis, University of Bern, February 2011). I have also [implemented](http://www.smalltalkhub.com/#!/~hernan/Subjectivity) the Darderes and Prieto model some years ago in Squeak.

Subjectivity provides a framework to determine which subjective behavior may be selected depending on the sender of a message, the receiver, or even the context, or any combination of such factors, even taking into account precedence or forces.

Although could be overwhelming for your purposes, implementing such approaches in pure textual technologies like mainstream languages may became a legendary task, because requires training in real object environment, and most implementations provides tools and/or recommendations for building specialized code browsers, which is where Smalltalk still shines.